# How can I restore deleted hooks in homepage?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I made a mess.
On the home page of my shop I've deleted some Hooks and maybe some modules from the Live Editor (Look at the images). I don't remember which ones I deleted and now not a single product is showing up. I would like to see again some products there, how can I do it?

thanks,
Lorenzo

[hooks deleted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdT8K.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I did this: you can modify each module, so you go in modules and click on the little arrow on the left of each module then click on reset (in italian is "reimposta"). Prestashop puts everything back in place.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not remember the modules canceled I see very difficult.

To re-connect the modules to its hook procedure is this:

Modules and Services -> Positions

the upper right corner you can find: "Transplant a module"

From this page, you just fill out the first two fields:

- Module (The module that you removed)
- Transplant to (set displayHomeTab and displayHomeTabContent)

good luck